# Is there any way to tell which tracks you've beaten TT's time on?

Tags: diddy-kong-racing

I'm trying to beat TT's time for all of the tracks to unlock him as a playable character. Is there any way to tell which tracks I haven't beaten him on yet, besides starting a new time trial race in every individual one and watching the ghost?

Comment: I thought the ghost was just your previous best run. (It's been a while, I could definitely be wrong.)

Comment: @user606723 Yes it is. And if your ghost beats TT then you know you're done with that track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that if you play from Tracks (not from Adventure) then an icon of TT will appear when selecting your vehicle if you've beaten him on that track.